# .hover on overlapping divs

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

i'm making a chrome extension where i add a border to whatever dom element the user's mouse is over.  my main problem is that when i rollover a div element with children the parent div and the child div both recieve a border when i only want the div directly under the mouse to receive the border.  here's a shortened version of my code:

```
$("*").hover(
function(e) {
    var targ = $(e.currentTarget);
    targ.css("border", "3px solid red");
},function(e){
    var targ = $(e.currentTarget);
    targ.css("border", "none");
}
);
```

is there a way the target can be ONLY the div directly under the mouse not the parent divs?

****figured it out but it's sooper hakey:

```
var killedObj;
var outlines=[];
var hovering=[];

$("*").not("body").not("head").each(
    function(i){
        outlines[i] = $(this).css("outline");
        hovering[i] = false;
        //console.log("index = " + i + " class name = " +  $(this).attr('class'));
        $(this).hover(
            function(){ 
                hovering[i]=true;
                if($(this).parents()!=null)killOutline($(this).parents(), outlines[$(this).parents().index()]); 
                if($(this).children()!=null)killOutline($(this).children(), outlines[$(this).children().index()]); 
                $(this).css("outline", "2px solid red");
            },function(){
                hovering[i]=false;
                $(this).css("outline", ""+outlines[i]);
                if($(this).parent()!=null){
                    if(hovering[i-1] == true){
                        resetOutline($(this).parent());
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
);

function killOutline(obj,outline){
    obj.css("outline", ""+outline);
}
function resetOutline(obj){
    obj.css("outline", "2px solid red");
}
```

if anybody has a cleaner way feel free

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: it's not working, but i might not be implementing it correctly?

Comment: I see your updated code now. This probably works for some sites, but if you're trying to allow outlines for any site the user browses to you're going to have problems where outlines that are supposed to be there get killed by your script. See my other suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching too many listeners on the page. To handle this you'll need just one.
Try to paste following code in console right here to test right on this page:

```
;(function() {
    var lastTarget;

    jQuery(document).on({
        mouseover: function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            lastTarget = jQuery(e.target);
            setState(lastTarget, true);
        },
        mouseout: function(e) {
            if(lastTarget) {
                setState(lastTarget, false);
            }
            lastTarget = null;
        }
    });

    var setState = function(block, state) {
        if(state) {
            block.css("outline", "3px solid red");
        } else {
            block.css("outline", "");
        }
    };

}());
```

As Jude Osborn said - it's better to create border and position it over target element rather then modifying inline styles (you can update this behavior in `setState` function).

Comment: beautiful!  i figured it out above but this is a lot better - thnx

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be possible to target only one item, because the results depend on how the CSS is set up for the site you are on. If a div's children are set to inherit their parent's border settings then they'll get a border when you set their parent's border.

You also probably can't cycle through a parent's children and remove their borders, because its possible the children actually need a border. It could get kind of tricky.

The best solution I can think of is to get the position, height and width of the item you are hovering over and create a new temporary div that rests overtop and that includes a border. This should create the desired effect.